# Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom:

Tags: apt

I am getting the following error msg when entering `sudo apt-get update` in terminal:

```
W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/ saucy/main i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2013.10%20%5fSaucy%20Salamander%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20131016.1)_dists_saucy_main_binary-i386_Packages)

W: Duplicate sources.list entry cdrom://Ubuntu 13.10 _Saucy Salamander_ - Release i386 (20131016.1)/ saucy/restricted i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/Ubuntu%2013.10%20%5fSaucy%20Salamander%5f%20-%20Release%20i386%20(20131016.1)_dists_saucy_restricted_binary-i386_Packages)
W: You may want to run apt-get update to correct these problems
```

I'm running Ubuntu from a flash-drive. I've run apt get update several times, to no avail. How do I correct these?

Answer (score -1):

Try removing everything in the /var/lib/apt/lists directory first (`sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*`) and then updating again.

Comment: tried it. received the following msg: cannot remove ‘/var/lib/apt/lists/partial’: Is a directory

Comment: Forgot about partial. Do `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*`.